# Errors when I rsync from a server to my local machine

Tags: rsync

I tried the following command to rsync from a server and got the following error message:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz name@home.com:/home/name/. .

receiving file list ... done
Desktop/Python_Nick/Python-2.4.1/
Desktop/Python_Nick/Python-2.4.1/Python/
Write failed: Broken pipe
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes [generator]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(1121) [generator=2.6.9]
rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(1197) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Sometimes it gives the following error:

```
Read from socket failed: Operation timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Then sometimes the following error:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (314764 bytes received so far) [receiver]rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes [generator]: Broken pipe (32)

rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(1121) [generator=2.6.9]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

I even tried using FETCH (The MAC application).
Any suggestions? The server is running LINUX and my local machine is a MAC

Comment: activate `ssh` verbose mode: `rsync -e 'ssh -vvv' --avz name@home.com:/home/name/. .`, what do you get?

Comment: Write failed: Broken pipe
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (1641213 bytes received so far) [receiver]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c, line=452): entered
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [receiver=2.6.9]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c, line=452): about to call exit(12)
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes [generator]: Broken pipe (32)

Comment: _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c, line=1121): entered
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(1121) [generator=2.6.9]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=/SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c, line=1121): about to call exit(255)

Comment: Update your question with the output for easier reading. In any case, I don't see any `ssh` debugging output there.

Comment: sorry, will do that in the future. It keeps saying "broken pipe" or rsync: connection unexpectedly closed

Comment: Don't you get anything different after adding the `-vvv` flags to `ssh`?

Comment: so I did not get anything different. It keeps closing the connection. so lets say I am on MAC1 and I want to rsync to MAC2, its when I get this error. If I try to put something ON MAC 2 (the one I was getting from, so in reverse) the connection is closed immediately ! I wonder if its to do with the other machine settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and my solution was to update rsync on my Mac.

As is clear from point 3 in the [rsync "current issues and debugging" page](https://rsync.samba.org/issues.html), the "connection unexpectedly closed"

> error tells you that the local rsync was trying to talk to the
>   remote rsync, but the connection to that rsync is now gone. The thing
>   you must figure out is why, and that can involve some investigative
>   work.

One of the first things suggested on this page is to update rsync. It turns out that Apple has not given us the latest rsync in their machines. Thus, I [updated the rsync version on my Mac via Macports](https://guide.macports.org) to 3.1.1. After that, I have had no problems syncing.

This is no general solution, of course, but then again there seem to *be* no general solution for this vague error message: if this had not worked, I had had to try and debug it. For details on how, see the above-mentioned rsync issues page.